# Как убрать заголовки при скачивании файла

Tags: c#

После выполнение данного кода

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
 File.WriteAllBytes("logo1.png",Convert.FromBase64String(client.DownloadString(URL")));
```

я получаю base64 строку,но она неверна потому,что еще и приписывается

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

Подскажите как убрать после получения base64

Comment: Как убрать что? А просто `Replace` не поможет?

Answer (score 3):

Замените DownloadString на DownloadFile - заголовки не будут скачиваться => проблема "как убрать из текста заголовок" пропадёт сама собой не появившись.

```
var url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVeie.jpg?s=328&g=1";
var filename = @"c:\downloads\logo1.png";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(url, filename);
```

Comment: мне нужен именно base64 - если качать файлом то в fidler видно

Comment: @Костя Вы хотите полученный файл преобразовать в строку base64? Уточните задачу, а то может быть вам и файл на диске не нужен (чтобы потом его не удалять) - [просто](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webclient_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) будем качать через WebClient.DownloadData сразу в массив байт данные с данного url - и на лету [конвертировать](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx) в base64 строку. Возможно, стоит привести пример url

Comment: @A K мне нужно,чтобы когда сайт получает сигнал а авторизации качалось моя dll (основное ядро) без видимости в fidler-е